# What's the difference between arimasu and desu (when referring to location)?

Tags: grammar

In Japanese, when describing the location of something you can say either `arimasu` and `desu`. E.g.

> a) Resutoran-wa ik-kai-ni arimasu

or

> b) Resutoran-wa ik-kai desu

What's the difference between a & b?

(a) uses `ni`, so that stresses the location.
(b) uses `desu` so it sounds more polite.
Is this correct?

Please note, this is a question about location. It is not a question about the difference between `arimasu` (exists/to be: non animate) and `imasu` (exists/to be: animate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both pretty polite, but I think you could say that there's an implied quantitative difference.

For example, when you say b 'restoran wa ikkai desu' to me, that sounds like the person is implying that there is only **one** restaurant, and it's on the first floor. Like 'As for the restaurant, it's on the first floor'.

But when you say a 'restoran wa ikkai ni arimasu' then that sound like it implies that there are *one or more* restaurants on the first floor. 'There is/are (a) restaurant/s on the first floor'.

Of course, Japanese is very vague so there's no singular/plural tell about the restaurants, and there's no definitive law about this -restoran wa ikkai desu could very well mean multiple restaurants are on the first floor too, there's nothing wrong with it grammatically- but that's what the implication sounds like to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any difference, other than that (b) is shorter and more common (both are very common). No difference in politeness because both use 丁寧語.

Source: Japanese native